# DocuSign user authenticates against developer, not production account

Tags: docusignapi

Wondering if someone has come across following and has thoughts/resolution options?

Consider following - user/customer has a DocuSign developer and live account.

User signs into browser using the developer account, entering username and password accordingly.  Cookies etc enabled.

User closes session and then commences signing process from an application that is integrated to DocuSign.  The integration uses Authorization Code Grant, so redirects the user's browser to login.

At this point, the signin details cached in the browser are used - so the user isn't asked to login.  The oauth token then generated is based on the developer/sandbox, but is then passed and used against the PROD integration, which obviously fails.

Is there a means when redirecting the user login that login can be "forced", or to supply an DocuSign accountID that must be authenticated against if the current cached login doesn't match?

Regards,
Nunya

Comment: Welcome! ***Please, check the best answer to your question. Thank you!***

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/70739795/64904

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: If your production app is using an active **developer** login session then the problem is that your production app needs to use account.docusign.com as the OAuth Service Provider. (It's incorrectly using account-d.docusign.com)

### More info

> User closes session and then commences signing process from an application that is integrated to DocuSign. The integration uses Authorization Code Grant, so redirects the user's browser to login.
>
> At this point, the signin details cached in the browser are used - so the user isn't asked to login. The oauth token then generated is based on the developer/sandbox, but is then passed and used against the PROD integration, which obviously fails.

No, the above is not the complete/correct story.
When an OAuth flow is initiated by the client, a specific `OAuth Service Provider` (the technical term) is used. For development, that's account-d.docusign.com. For production, that's account.docusign.com.

Yes, by default, an active login session cookie **from the same OAuth Service Provider** will enable both the Authorization Code and Implicit grant flows to skip the authentication step.

But if your production app is using an active developer login session then the problem is that your production app needs to use account.docusign.com

If you're using a DocuSign SDK then you need to explicitly set the SDK to use account.docusign.com.

> Is there a means when redirecting the user login that login can be "forced", or to supply an DocuSign accountID that must be authenticated against if the current cached login doesn't match?

Yes, via the OAuth initial request, you can require the user to authenticate. -- If there is a current login session cookie, it will be ignored.

To turn off "silent authentication": add a query parameter and value -- `prompt=login` [Docs](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/reference/obtain-consent/)

Comment: Hi Larry - yep, that's what we're doing - account.docusign.com for PROD, account-d.docusign.com for the sandbox.  I think I now know what's going on.

1. Some developer staff have their own sandbox accounts.  If they've logged into that, then those details are being used, rather than the account we want them to use.  The prompt=login option will help there.

2. I've had one customer who had two docusign accounts, which were rationalised.  But some users were logged in on the old accounts.    Is there are way to specify the AccountID (not user ID) to be used during login?

Comment: See this q & a: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70739795/64904