# DocuSign specify account for login

Tags: docusignapi

Some of my application's users have access to more than one DocuSign account. My app is designed to be used with a specific DocuSign account.

Can I specify the DocuSign account during login?

Answer (score 0):

No. With DocuSign, a person authenticates themself as a user, not as a user for a specific account.

However, once the person has completed authentication, your software should use the [/oauth/userinfo](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/reference/user-info/) API call to learn which accounts the user has access to. This API call is also used to learn the user's name and email.

The /oauth/userinfo results will include an array of the accounts that the user is a member of (has access to). The array includes:

- the account guid
- the account name
- the base URL for API calls to the account
- whether the account is the user's default account or not

If your application is designed to work with a specific DocuSign account, then your software should check that the user has access to that account and give a clear error message if there's an issue.

If your application can work with any of a user's accounts, then the best pattern is to:

1. use the user's `default` account
2. enable the user to change which of their accounts your application will use

### Notes

The /oauth/userinfo API call is available from the DocuSign OAuth service providers:

- https://account.docusign.com (production)
- https://account-d.docusign.com (development)

The /oauth/userinfo API supports CORS, so it can be used directly from browser-based apps